# Best Method for iOS Application to Update & Retrieve Files from SQL Server?

Tags: ios, sql, ruby-on-rails, web-services

First let me say in advance that after having done a bit of research, I am aware that there is a ton of information regarding this question.  A bit overwhelmed, I wanted to consolidate the approaches that I have found into one question and ask for confirmation as to whether each step in the path is:

1. The best resource/method to accomplish this task and
2. All encompassing (is there a gap in functionality I am not aware of)

I have written an iOS app which currently stores/loads data from a parsed csv file on the app's Documents path.  Currently I must manually place the data to and retrieve the data from disk by connecting the device to my computer, and then take this csv file and enter into SQL.  The next step in development is for me to perform this task via a web service of some kind which automates the process for me when I update/record data in the application.  However I have no experience with this!

So after looking into this process, I think I have split the task into the following components, beginning and ending with the app and a SQL server:

- ___iOS App
- __[RestKit Framework](http://restkit.org/) to communicate w/ web service using JSON
- _[Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) RESTful Web Service
- __[ActiveRecord Gem](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html) to communicate w/ SQL server using JSON
- ___SQL Server

At this point I have almost zero knowledge of RestKit, RoR, or ActiveRecord, and so before I dive in headfirst I want to be confident that comprehensively, hooking these elements together will provide the medium for communication between my app and a SQL database that I am looking for and that I am going about this the right way.

So am I on the right track?  Is there anything else I should be aware of? Is this how you would accomplish the same thing?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need SQL? How good are you with PHP? I get and push my data to my Postgres server with a custom API that my coworker whipped up for me. All I do is supply the URL using NSURL request and the API turns that into a Postgres query. Works for both getting and giving data.

Comment: MMhmmm.  That sounds really straightforward actually! But unfortunately besides the fact that I don't know PHP :(, it really just has to be SQL.  And I don't say that to be stubborn, but details aside its really the only option.